# How to scroll Telegram page with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scroll, telegram

It seems like a simple task, but it isn't. I've been trying for a few days to find a way to scroll through a **group page** on Telegram using Selenium, but it seems that somehow Telegram makes this action impossible. I've tried all the following conventional ways and failed:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "")
element.click()
element.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_UP)
element.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)


driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight);")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -100);")
```

I'm almost sure that Telegram blocks the use of JavaScript commands because when I use the following commands in the Console, it doesn't scroll the page

```
window.scrollBy(0, -100);
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try .
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element)`
and in selenium version of 4.11 supporting scroll by mouse.
The worst outcome is pyautogui, it can control you keyboard and mouse.